# FactoryGirl error during Run Rake Task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, factory-bot

I am having an issue with FactoryGirl when running Rake Tasks.

Here is my current setup on my Windows 7 laptop:

1) RubyMine 4.5
2) Rails 3.2.8
3) Ruby 1.9.3
4) PostgreSQL 9.1 
5) rspec-rails 2.11.0
6) capybara 1.1.2
7) factory_girl_rails 4.0
8) shoulda

Here is my spec_helper.rb file:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'development'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

require 'factory_girl'

#Support for capybara
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ## Mock Framework
  #
  # If you prefer to use mocha, flexmock or RR, uncomment the appropriate line:
  #
  # config.mock_with :mocha
  # config.mock_with :flexmock
  # config.mock_with :rr
  config.mock_with :rspec

  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
  # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
  # rspec-rails.
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = "random"
end

#spec for authentication
def login_user
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)

  visit new_user_session_path
  fill_in "Email", :with=> @user.email
  fill_in "Password", :with=> @user.password

  click_button "Sign In"
end
```

Here is my authentication_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Sign Out link" do
  it "should sign you out when clicked" do
    login_user
    page.should have_content("Signed in as")
  end
end
```

**Here is my error message with the trace:**

```
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\Ruby193\bin\rake spec:requests --trace
Testing started at 11:51 AM ...
** Invoke spec:requests (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "authentications_id_seq" for serial column "authentications.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "authentications_pkey" for table "authentications"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "categories_id_seq" for serial column "categories.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "categories_pkey" for table "categories"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "sub_categories_id_seq" for serial column "sub_categories.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "sub_categories_pkey" for table "sub_categories"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "users_id_seq" for serial column "users.id"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "users_pkey" for table "users"
** Execute spec:requests
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -S rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb

**ArgumentError: Factory not registered: users**
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:71:in `factory_by_name'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:12:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/factory_girl-4.0.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
C:/Users/Rich/RubymineProjects/EquipmentTrader/spec/spec_helper.rb:49:in `login_user'
C:/Users/Rich/RubymineProjects/EquipmentTrader/spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in `instance_eval'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:113:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:253:in `with_around_each_hooks'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:110:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:378:in `block in run_examples'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:374:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:374:in `run_examples'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:360:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `map'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:28:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 0.008001 seconds
rake aborted!
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -S rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb failed
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:137:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:60:in `verbose'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb:127:in `block in initialize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
C:/Ruby193/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => spec:requests

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am not sure how I need to resolve this issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `:user` factory defined? Are you sure it is being included? Normally that would happen in `spec_helper.rb`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because your `spec_helper.rb` once referenced `FactoryGirl.create(:users)` -- note the plural -- rather than `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`. If you saved `spec_helper.rb` as you have it in the question, then it will work. The only situation where I can think it would show the error that you're saying that it's showing is that if this file was not saved.